# Usage of AllocaInst with example: LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am very new to **LLVM** and I would like to know the proper usage of AllocaInst with examples. I tried searching online and even the llvm webpage does not have the right examples for it.
Below is the patch of code I am trying to execute.

```
string temp =(dyn_cast<ConstantInt>operand0))->getValue()).toString(10,true);
Type* A = IntegerType::getInt32Ty(F.getContext());
string name = "t"+to_string(++counter);
AllocaInst* variable = new AllocaInst(A,NULL,4,name,&*inst);
```

When I run this, I will get an error:

> error:no matching function for call to 'llvm::AllocaInst::AllocaInst(llvm::Type*&, NULL, int, std::string&, llvm::Instruction*)'
>        AllocaInst* variable = new AllocaInst(A,NULL,4,name,&*inst);

I would like to know how do I provide an address location with in AllcaInst. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your LLVM C++ library version in synch with the C++ header you are using?

Comment: What is the "4" for?

Comment: This is the array size. LLVM C++ and  C++ header are in synch

Answer (score 2):

You cannot initialize an array this way. The problem of your code is the array size. `AllocaInst` expects an `llvm::Value*` for the array size, i.e., the size must live in the IR. To get a constant 4 you have to use `ConstantInt::get` to create a constant integer value in the IR. The `ConstantInt*` can be provided to the AllocaInst constructor.